# How to configure DynamoDB retryLimit and retryDelay in Node js API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have pretty high traffic peaks, thus I'd like to overwrite the dynamodb retry limit and retry policy.

Somehow I'm not able to find the right config property to overwrite the retry limit and function.

my code so far

```
var aws = require( 'aws-sdk');
var table = new aws.DynamoDB({params: {TableName: 'MyTable'}});
aws.config.update({accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY});
aws.config.region = 'eu-central-1';
```

I found the following amazon variables and code snippets, however I'm not sure how to wire this up with the config?

```
retryLimit: 15,
retryDelays: function retryDelays() {
    var retryCount = this.numRetries();
    var delays = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < retryCount; ++i) {
        if (i === 0) {
            delays.push(0);
        } else {
            delays.push(60*1000 *i); // Retry every minute instead
            // Amazon Defaultdelays.push(50 * Math.pow(2, i - 1));
        }
    }
    return delays;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The config is pretty limited, and the only retry parameter you can set on it is `maxRetries`.

```
maxRetries (Integer) — the maximum amount of retries to attempt with a request. See AWS.DynamoDB.maxRetries for more information.
```

You should set the maxRetries to a value that is appropriate to your use case.

```
aws.config.maxRetries = 20;
```

The `retryDelays` private API uses internally the `maxRetries` config setting, so setting that parameter globally like in my code above should work. The `retryLimit` is completely useless, and forget about it.

The number of retries can be set through configuration, but seems that there is not an elegant way to set the retry delay/backoff strategy etc.

The only way to manipulate those is to listen to the `retry` event, and manipulate the retry delay (and related behavior) in a event handler callback:

```
aws.events.on('retry', function(resp) {

    // Enable or disable retries completely.
    // disabling is equivalent to setting maxRetries to 0.
    if (resp.error) resp.error.retryable = true;

    // retry all requests with a 2sec delay (if they are retryable)
    if (resp.error) resp.error.retryDelay = 2000;

});
```

Be aware that there is an exponential backoff strategy that runs internally, so the retryDelay is not literally 2s for subsequent retries. If you look at the internal service.js file you will see how the function looks:

```
retryDelays: function retryDelays() {
  var retryCount = this.numRetries();
  var delays = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < retryCount; ++i) {
    delays[i] = Math.pow(2, i) * 30;
  }
  return delays;
}
```

I don't think it's a good idea to modify internal API's, but you could do it by modifying the prototype of the Service class:

```
aws.Service.prototype.retryDelays = function(){ // Do some }
```

However, this will affect all services, and after looking in depth at this stuff, it is obvious their API wasn't built to cover your use-case in an elegant way, through configuration.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  however is it possible to change this only for dynamo? How does the internal exponential back-off algorithm affect the delay? Eg if I set delay time to 1min and the exponential back-off ads another 5min this may not be my intension.

Comment: So basically is it possible to overwrite the delay completely? And is there any tineout limit for the total of all retries? E.g try every 1min up to 5min?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to listen to an event specific to dynamodb. The formula used internally is (50 * Math.pow(2, retryIndex - 1)) so you can do the math :) It is possible to overwrite the delay, but you would have to modify the internal retryDelay function which could be dangerous. I have updated the answer with more details.

Answer (score 5):

The javascript AWS SDK does not allow the DynamoDB service to overwrite the `retryDelayOptions` and thus does not allow the `customBackoff` to be defined.  These configurations are allowed for the rest of the services, but for some reason does not work for DynamoDB.

[This page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#retryDelayOptions-property) notes that :

> Note: This works with all services except DynamoDB.

Therefore, if you want to define a `customBackoff` function, ie: determine a `retryDelay`, it is not possible through configuration.  The only way I have found was to overwrite the private method `retryDelays` of the DynamoDB object (`aws-sdk-js/lib/services/dynamodb.js`).

Here is an example of this being done where a exponential backoff with jitter is implemented :

```
AWS.DynamoDB.prototype.retryDelays = (retryCount: number): number => {
    
    let temp = Math.min(cap, base * Math.pow(2, retryCount));
    let sleep = Math.random() * temp + 1;
    return sleep;
};
```

Max retries or retry limit can be set through the `maxRetries` property of the DynamoDB configuration object as such :

```
let dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    maxRetries: 30
});
```

---

#### See Also :

- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/402
- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1171
- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1100
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html#Programming.Errors.RetryAndBackoff
- https://www.awsarchitectureblog.com/2015/03/backoff.html

Comment: it has been fixed, `customBackoff` can now be used :)